# CAML query list created date +2

Tags: caml

I am wanted to query a list which brings back items which are greater than 2 days old. I am unsure how the CAML query should look. Below is my code

```
<Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
        <Value Type="Choice">NEW</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
        <Value Type="DateTime">
              what goes here
        </Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use the Greater than or Equal operator (`Geq`) and then use the [`Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460496.aspx) element for relative comparison:

```
<Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
        <Value Type="Choice">NEW</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
        <Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-2" /></Value>
      </Geq>
    </And>
</Where>
```